# Error resolving module specifier: logrocket, using npm or yarn

Tags: javascript, npm, module, yarnpkg, logrocket

I'm trying to initialize `LogRocket`, using 
[official doc](https://docs.logrocket.com/reference#init):

- successfully installed it with node: `npm i --save logrocket`
- But when trying to initiate it earlier on my page using

```
    <script type="module">
        // init LogRocket
        import LogRocket from 'logrocket'
        LogRocket.init("my/project/id")
    </script>
```

I get this error `Uncaught TypeError: Error resolving module specifier: logrocket`. 
Note that I can open the logrocket module by `Cmd+click` on the `from 'logrocket'`.

And I can use logrocket for non-npm approach

```
<script src="https://cdn.lr-ingest.io/LogRocket.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>window.LogRocket && window.LogRocket.init('my/project/id');</script>
```

Does anyone already faced such issue ? How to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

I think they at some point changed the way exporting, the doc is out-of-date.

Before I only succeed by using

```
import * as LogRocket from 'logrocket';
```

But I just tried again now, both

```
import * as LogRocket from 'logrocket';
import LogRocket from 'logrocket';
```

work for me.

Tested on logrocket version 1.0.12